# How to replace a HTML String with img tags using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

We have some content coming from the backend api into an Ionic 2 App. Questions and Answers. Answers have been created using summernote and hence we're able to render raw HTML into the app. But to allow zooming of images, we need to replace all the occurrences of **img** tag in the answer content.

```
<img src="pathofimg" attribute1="att1" ...>
```

With

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
  <img src="pathofimg" attribute1="att1" ...>
</ion-scroll>
```

Using only **pure javascript**.

I know regex is the good approach but open for suggestions.

Comment: Text based replacement, with regex, is probably the easiest and quickest method. DOM manipulation can be slow, especially if there are lots of tags to modify.

Comment: Using regex on html? [Fun, fun...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/615754)

Comment: Yup. I know its not so easy but that's the only way to do without using jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this wraps each child element `<span>` into a wrapper element `<p>`. Simply replace the element names and selectors with your own. You may want to use `document.querySelector()` if your parent element isn't easy to select.

```
<div>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>

<script>
    var commonParentElement = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    var imgs = commonParentElement.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
      var wrap = document.createElement('p');
      wrap.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold;');
      wrap.appendChild(imgs[i]);
      commonParentElement.insertBefore(wrap, imgs[i]);
    }
</script>
```

[Here in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oUXKbeYxsL5RLQto4yJj?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We won't be able to get document.getElementsByTagName as its an ionic app. We need to make it work upon the string directly. Not the rendered div.

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know that. Can you use Angular's jqLite?

Answer (score 0):

As you added only `javascript` tag to your question, here is solution using "native" `document.getElementsByTagName` and `element.replaceChild` methods:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    len = images.length, img, ion, parent;

while (len--) {
    ion = document.createElement("ion-scroll");
    ion.setAttribute("scrollX", "true");
    ion.setAttribute("scrollY", "true");

    img = images[len];
    parent = img.parentNode;
    ion.innerHTML = img.outerHTML;
    parent.replaceChild(ion, img);
}
```